# magento 2 restrict pin code for shipping

Tags: magento2

Hi hope all are doing well in this pandemic

I am running a Client site and they want to restrict pin code for shipping in red zone

I have an excel sheet of pin code which they want to allow shipping.

how can I achieve this I can't found any free extension

anyone kindly help magento 2 restrict pin code for shipping

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the excel sheet data to the database table (by your script) and you can add validation to zip code based on that data.

It will allow only those locations which are in your database and for others, you can add a warning message

You can refer the following link

https://github.com/MeetanshiInc/Magento-Restrict-Zip-Codes

Hope this will help you.

Happy Coding.

Comment: this extension is for magento 1 and i need solution for magento 2

Comment: I found this extension 
https://github.com/vrajeshpatel4u/v4u-magento2-check-delivery-availability
I am able to show pin code that are available but i want cart button disabled until user check his pin code or may be disable shipping method if user fill the address form

Comment: if you can give me some guide to add pin codes in database will be very thankful